# Using the Output of union in exists Condition

Tags: sql

I am having three tables T1,T2,T3

I want to achieve something like

```
Select T1.X,T1.Y,
exists(

( select T2.Z from T2
  union
  select T3.Z from T3 ) Result where Result.Z=T1.Y
) from T1
```

SQL is giving me the syantx, please help me how to achieve this result ?

```
T1 Contains
X Y
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 7

T2 Contains
Z
1
2

T3 Contains
3
4
```

Union of T2 and T3

```
1 2 3 4
```

And now Checks if T1 contains theses rows

```
OutPut

X  Y  Contains
1  0  True
1  1  True
1  2  True
1  7  False
```

Comment: I fail to clearly understand. Do you want a third column that tells you if there's matching row?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: updated with an example

Comment: @The_learning_guy Still doesn't answer which dbms?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `case` expression with two `exists` clauses:

```
Select t2.X, t1.Y,
       (case when exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.z = t1.y then 1
             when exists (select 1 from t3 where t3.z = t1.y then 1
            else 0
        end) as matches
from t1;
```

Note that `exists` is better than `count(*)` in a subquery because it is faster.  First, it can readily take advantage of an index (`t2(z)` and `t3(z)`).  Second, it can stop at the first match.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select T1.X,T1.Y, ( select case when count(*)>0 then 'true' else 'false' end from
( select T2.Z from T2 union select T3.Z from T3 ) Result where Result.Z=T1.Y )
from T1
```

This will result in:

```
    X   Y   (No column name)
1   1   0   false
2   1   1   true
3   1   2   true
4   1   7   false
```

See here: http://rextester.com/XDW34718 (SQL-Server)
and here: http://rextester.com/VXBN87216 (MySql)

The results `true` and `false` are actually strings here. To my knowledge the real boolean values are usually represented by `1` and `0`. And `exists` is only allowed as part of the `where` clause.

Alternatively you could do it with a sum of two `count(*)` values like

SQL-Server:  http://rextester.com/GBKNRJ77523

```
Select x,y, 
  CAST ((select count(*) from t2 where z=y)
       +(select count(*) from t3 where z=y) as bit) [Contains]
from T1
```

MySQL:  http://rextester.com/AWOKZ51875

```
Select x,y, 
  (select count(*) from t2 where z=y)
 +(select count(*) from t3 where z=y)>0 `Contains`
from T1
```

Comment: In standard SQL, `case when count(*)>0 then 'true' else 'false' end` can be simplified to `count(*)>0`

Comment: @horse_with_no_name: probably true. I tested in sql-server and there it will not be accepted.

Comment: Btw: that's because SQL Server has no real boolean data type (and neither does MySQL). Real boolean values are expressed as `true` or `false` in (standard) SQL